# SharePoint 2010 - Add list item with workflow approval status and PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

I want to add a item to a SharePoint 2010 list by using PowerShell.
This list is related with the standard SharePoint Approval Workflow.
I want to add Items and set the workflow status to "Published" with PowerShell.
My Code, but how it is possible to set the Workflow status to "Published"?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $Url
$list = $web.Lists["MyList"]
$newitem =    $Schulliste.items.Add()
$newitem["Column1"] = "Test1" # Works fine!


#Set Column Writable
$column = $list.Fields["WorkflowName"]
$column.Hidden = $false
$column.ReadOnlyField = $false
$column.Update()

#Update Workflow Item
$newitem["WorkflowName"] = "Published" #Not working
$newitem.update()

#Set Column Readonly
$column = $list.Fields["WorkflowName"]
$column.Hidden = $true
$column.ReadOnlyField = $true
$column.Update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround now is to activate and deactivate the content approval

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $Url        
$list = $Web.Lists["MyList"]  

$list.EnableModeration = $false 
$list.Update()

$newitem =    $liste.items.Add()   
$newitem["Column1"] = "Test1" 
$newitem.update()

$list.EnableModeration = $true 
$list.Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, setting the Status field is not the right way. You should approve the item programatically.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.approve.aspx

```
$newitem.File.Approve("approved by script")
```

Comment: damn! This only works with a document library but I´m using a list! Thanks for your post, nice to know!